# Proof of Cauchy's theorem for finite groups in Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

The proof in Dummit & Foote is the familiar induction proof.
$\require{amssymb}$

> $G$ is an abelian group. Let $N = \langle x \rangle$ for some $x \in G$. Since $G$ is abelian, $N \trianglelefteq G$. We use induction to conclude that $G \, / \, N$ has an element $\bar{y} = yN$ of order $p$, where $p$ is prime, since $|G \, / \, N| < |G|$ and $p$ divides $|G|$ but $p$ does not divide $|N|$.

My question is, if $|yN| = p$ and all cosets have the same order, why can't we conclude $|yN| = |N| = |x| = p$?

Or, more accurately, how can we say $p$ does not divide |$N$|, then show that $p = |yN|$. Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: There's an ambiguity here. "an element $\overline{y} = yN$ of order $p$" means (in this context at least), that $(\overline{y})^p = \overline{1}$, not that $|yN| = p$.

Comment: By the way, the proof seems slightly wrong as stated. If $x$ itself is of order $p$ then we're done (and $G/\langle x \rangle$ need not have an element of order $p$). **Otherwise** $G/\langle x \rangle$ has an element of order $p$ and we can proceed inductively.

Comment: $x$ is not of order $p$, since $p$ does not divide $|N| = |\langle x \rangle|$.

Comment: Why doesn't $p$ divide $|N| = |\langle x \rangle|$? If $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $G$ then it might. That's why I'm saying that the proof is slightly misstated.

Comment: I only posted the part of the proof relevant to the question. Yes, the entire proof considers that case too. I actually had no issue with the proof in and of itself, just thought I was seeing a shortcut despite there likely not being any, and wanted to know what my mistake was.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for the context. By the way, the theorem is true for nonabelian groups as well, but the proof has to be modified somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different concepts of order. Yes, $yN$ has order $p$ as an element of $G/N$. That does *not* mean that $\#yN=p$. What it means is that $y^pN=N$; in other words, $y^p\in N$.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case after applying the idea to $\langle r^2 \rangle$ in $D_8$ and $s \langle r^2 \rangle$. I just think the terminology is a bit confusing, since coset order is also used to denote the number of elements in the coset.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)